# Check if a User Has a Gravatar [WordPress]

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Thanks **Rene Korss** for helping to resolve the issue almost and be there every time to reply in discussion.

I want to check if the user who has posted comment is having an avatar or not? If user has avatar (means having gravatar account) show gravatar avatar else show image which I have defined in else portion. Any help would be appriciated.

**I am currently using this code:**

```
if(get_avatar()==1 )
            {
                echo get_avatar($comment,$size='48',$default='<path_to_url>' ); 
            }
        else
            {   ?>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/admin.jpg" alt=""><?php 
            }   ?>
```

Output for this code is only else portion working. And in case I am writing condition as `if(get_avatar())` then only if portion working.

**$comment has values:**

```
 stdClass Object ( 
 [comment_ID] => 9 
 [comment_post_ID] => 104 
 [comment_author] => Navnish 
 [comment_author_email] => ask@navnishbhardwaj.com
 [comment_author_url] => 
 [comment_author_IP] => 118.146.54.35 
 [comment_date] => 2015-09-23 14:33:11 
 [comment_date_gmt] => 2015-09-23 14:33:11 
 [comment_content] => this is comment by Admin
 [comment_karma] => 0 
 [comment_approved] => 1 
 [comment_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0 
 [comment_type] => 
 [comment_parent] => 0 
 [user_id] => 1 
 )
```

**When used this code:**

```
<?php 
$avatar = get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), $size = '48', $default = bloginfo( 'template_directory' ).'/img/admin.jpg' ); 
if( $avatar !== false )
{
echo $avatar; 
} 
?>
```

**Got output like this:**

[image]

**Output for:**

```
$avatar = get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, $size = '48', $default = bloginfo( 'template_directory' ).'/img/admin.jpg' ); 
if( $avatar !== false )
{
    echo $avatar; 
}
```

**is:**
[image]

Comment: Show us how you get `$comment`.

Comment: $comment is stdClass Object. I have updated value of $comment in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this. Using author email should help. Also, notice that I'm not calling `get_avatar` twice. `else` is not needed, because you can set `$default` image to be used, if avatar dosen't exist.

```
$avatar = get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, $size = '48', $default = bloginfo( 'template_directory' ).'/img/admin.jpg' ); 
if( $avatar !== false )
{
    echo $avatar; 
}
```

Comment: Getting error. Updated question with this code's output. Please have a look on it.

Comment: It's not a error. It looks like URL of avatar? But it shouldn't. Whats missing images `src`?

Comment: Tried img src. But, only my defined image is working. Gravatar avtar is not working. You can say, its returning as else result for code we used in start.

Comment: Okay. Edited my answer. Please try again.

Comment: I think we are almost near to it.. :) Have a look on what result I got now. Updated at the end of question.

Comment: Do you know where that `http://192..` comes from? Missing image is probably your `$default` image, what dosen't exist?

Comment: But where it gets printed? Can you make sure that broken image exists?

Comment: when I am writing $default ='' its working fine. If user has Gravatar avtar showing that. Otherwise displaying default mistry man. Which is displayed in discussion [WordPress Dashboard]

Comment: I am ok with this too. But I want to display own image not mistry man image. To change mistry man I used these two link http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-default-gravatar-on-wordpress/ and http://seohour.com/how-to-change-the-default-gravatar-mystery-man-on-wordpress-blog-12171/.

But, its not displaying image in discussion section [WordPress Dashboard]

Comment: This is actually another question how to override default avatar globally on WP. You have to use filter on `get_avatar` hook.

Comment: I agree. This is another question. But, I realized we can achieve required result by this method too.. By the way thankyou for your support in all this. I am marking your answer as correct accepted and up-voting too for all efforts you did for me and community.

Answer (score 4):

Another, more versatile approach: when you don't want to get the default image from the gravatar service in case an avatar does not exist, but you just want to know it to possibly provide your own local image in that case or do something else, then you can use the function proposed by [Wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars#Checking_for_the_Existence_of_a_Gravatar).

```
function validate_gravatar($email) {
    // Craft a potential url and test its headers
    $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($email)));
    $uri = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . $hash . '?d=404';
    $headers = @get_headers($uri);
    if (!preg_match("|200|", $headers[0])) {
        $has_valid_avatar = FALSE;
    } else {
        $has_valid_avatar = TRUE;
    }
    return $has_valid_avatar;
}
```

(You ask the gravatar service for the image giving specifying "404" as the default "image", and then you check what was the server's answer)

The downside of this approach is that you have to make some additional HTTP requests for each avatar to check it, so that slows down everything a little.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (get_avatar_data( $id_or_email )['found_avatar'])
```

Will check if the user has a gravatar image set.

[get_avatar_data](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_data/)

Answer (score 0):

`get_avatar()` retrieve the avatar for a user who provided a user ID or email address. It returns true if avatar exists.

```
if(get_avatar($comment))
 {
   echo get_avatar($comment,$size='48',$default='<path_to_url>' ); 
 }
 else
 {   ?>
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/admin.jpg" alt=""><?php 
 }
```

Comment: Still only IF section working same as  if(get_avatar() )

Comment: How you are getting $comment

Comment: Using a function as argument. I have updated values of $comment in question.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(get_avatar('user_id')==1 )
            {
                echo get_avatar($comment,$size='48',$default='<path_to_url>' ); 
            }
        else
            {   ?>
       <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');>/img/admin.jpg" alt=""><?php 
            }   ?>
```

Use `get_avatar( 'id')` instead of `get_avatar( )`  use some id

Comment: When I write if(get_avatar()=1) it don't return anything. Website stops working in this case. complete White page only

Comment: if(get_avatar('user_id')==1 ) only else section working now.

Comment: try this  if(get_avatar('comment_approved')==1 )

Comment: Implemented this. But, still working only else portion

Comment: if(get_avatar('comment_approved')==0 ) try this